# Create single variation for woocommerce product

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce, parent-child

i need to create a single variation for any woocommerce product, however each time i hit save it creates another variation.
i'm working outside of the loop from functions.php

why each time i hit save it creates another variation, need help to create just 1 variation/child post

```
add_action (save_post, create_new_vars);
function create_new_vars ($post) {
global $post;
$children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
if( count( $children ) >= 1 ) {     
return;
}

$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'Color  for #' . $post->ID,
    'post_name' => get_the_title($post->ID),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'product_variation',
    'guid' => home_url() . '/?product_variation=' . get_the_title($post->ID)
);

    remove_action('save_post', __FUNCTION__);
    $attID = wp_insert_post($my_post);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok answer is

```
add_action (save_post, create_new_vars);
function create_new_vars ($post) {
global $post;
$args  = array(
    'post_title' => 'Color  for #' . $post->ID,
    'post_name' => get_the_title($post->ID),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'product_variation',
    'guid' => home_url() . '/?product_variation=' . get_the_title($post->ID)    
);
$children = get_children( $args );
if( count( $children ) < 1 ) {      


$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'Color  for #' . $post->ID,
    'post_name' => get_the_title($post->ID),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'product_variation',
    'guid' => home_url() . '/?product_variation=' . get_the_title($post->ID)
);

    remove_action('save_post', __FUNCTION__);
    $attID = wp_insert_post($my_post);

}
}
```